# How to measure the mass of an uncharged particle like a neutron?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, mass, neutrons

How we can measure the mass of a neutral particles like neutron? To measure the mass of a charge particles like electron we use mass spectroscopy. What about uncharged particles?

Comment: Wikipedia has a link to the paper describing the first accurate measurement http://www.nature.com/physics/looking-back/chadwick2/index.html

Comment: A particle can be neutral and still have a magnetic moment (like the neutron). Are you excluding this possibility also?

Answer (score 1):

> To measure the mass of a charged particles like electron we use mass spectroscopy. What about uncharged particles?

For the neutron there exists a [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_mass#Mass) paragraph as mentioned in the comments.

One has to use interactions and conservation laws. The mass of the pi0 is the invariant mass of the two gammas it decays into. K0 has a pi+pi- decay mode. Lamda a proton pi-.

This works as long as the masses are larger than the measurement errors. Neutrinos were only bounded to have mass because of the observation of [neutrino oscillations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_oscillation), and only ratios and bounds have been found.